# htaccess: Possible to make if queries for the same url?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to query an URL for the included ID and then redirect to different files according to the ID. I tried with RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} but it's not working out. Please help.

This is the sample URL which needs to be redirected:
http://www.example.com/people/123456.html, where 123456 is the user ID.

If user ID is >= 300000 and <= 399999, 
redirect to http://www.example.com/people/profile-old.php&userid=xxx

If user ID is >= 400000 and <= 499999, 
redirect to http://www.example.com/people/profile-1.php&userid=xxx

Else redirect to http://www.example.com/people/profile-2.php&userid=xxx

Comment: I think you'll have to use a server-side script for this (looks like you're running PHP?). I don't know of any way to do numerical comparison in a rewrite rule. Rewrite everything that matches /people to a people-router.php and do the redirecting in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule people/(3[0-9]{5})\.html /people/profile-old.php&userid=$1
RewriteRule people/(4[0-9]{5})\.html /people/profile-1.php&userid=$1
RewriteRule people/([0-9]+)\.html /people/profile-2.php&userid=$1
```

(I think the `&` should be a `?` though)